# Django Admin Site displays the list of 'XXXObject' rather than directly displaying the details of the Objects

Tags: django, django-admin

[These are the Apps added from the Model Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OunxG.png)

[I want it to directly display the details of the Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADsuk.png)

The attributes of the Leave_Details class are start_date,end_date,details..
Please click on the image link.
How can I directly display the attributes of all the Leave_Object class in Home>App>Leave_statuss

Display it just like the inbuilt Users model i.e. in a systematic table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define Admin class derived from `admin.ModelAdmin` and define your fields like follows:

in `admin.py` of your app define

```
class LeaveDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['start_date', 'end_date']

admin.site.register(Leave_Details, LeaveDetailsAdmin)
```

RTFM :) - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/
To be more specific: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Comment: list_display should be a tuple.. Thanks (y)

Comment: ah, docs says so. although, list_display could be a list as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return self.[attribute_name]
```

to retrive the Object's name as attribute_name.

Comment: I want to make it look like the in-buit User page, that displays a proper table.

Comment: hopefully, you use Python 3.x so you have to override `__str__` instead

Comment: Yup, I used __str__ only, but how display it like a proper table

Comment: please, see my answer below